# Count of person with Age Range to display in Bar Chart

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with thousands of records and sample is given below.

There is only `[DateOfBirth]` field in the table and I need to calculate age range with total count :

```
ID         Name             DateOfBirth 
1          John             1980-11-20 00:00:00.000
2          Denial           1940-04-10 00:00:00.000
3          Binney           1995-12-25 00:00:00.000
4          Sara             1960-11-20 00:00:00.000
5          Poma             1980-11-20 00:00:00.000
6          Cameroon         1980-11-20 00:00:00.000
.....
.....
```

I need to write the SQL Query to display output 10 years age range to fit it in the bar chart.

```
AgeRange        Count
1-10            100
11-20           200
21-30           400
31-40           0
41-50           800
51-60           700
61-70           200
.....
.....
```

and so on if the age person is present in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below query

```
 select 
    cast( 1 + DateDiff(YY,DATEADD(YY,-1,DateOfBirth),getdate())/10 *10 as varchar)+ '-'+ cast(10+ DateDiff(YY,DATEADD(YY,-1,DateOfBirth),getdate())/10 *10 as varchar) as AgeRange
    ,
    count(1) as count
    from tbl
    group by 
    DateDiff(YY,DATEADD(YY,-1,DateOfBirth),getdate())/10
```

<kbd>**[Demo link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0887e/5)**</kbd>

update: based on your custom range, you should use this query

```
select 
cast(case when 
DateDiff(YY,DATEADD(YY,-1,DateOfBirth),getdate())/10 =0
then 0
else 
1 end+ DateDiff(YY,DATEADD(YY,-1,DateOfBirth),getdate())/10 *10 as varchar)+ '-'+ cast(10+ DateDiff(YY,DATEADD(YY,-1,DateOfBirth),getdate())/10 *10 as varchar) as AgeRange
,
count(1) as count
from tbl
group by 
DateDiff(YY,DATEADD(YY,-1,DateOfBirth),getdate())/10
```

Comment: Is is showing the result as below:     
Age Range    Count
-825--824       1
399-400       1
594-595       1
947-948       1
1290-1291 2
1678-1679 1
2384-2385 1
2673-2674 1

I need 10 years date range instead. Thank you very much quick response.

Comment: @DPBhatt I see that your ranges are incorrect , you started with `0-10` and then `11-20`... do you need exactly this or `0-9` , `10-19` or `1-10` , `11-20`

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work for me

```
  SELECT count(*) as [count] 
       , cast(datediff(YYYY, value, getdate())/10 * 10 as varchar(10)) + ' - ' + 
         cast(datediff(YYYY, value, getdate())/10 * 10 + 9 as varchar(10)) as range
    FROM [docSVdate] 
   group by datediff(YYYY, value, getdate())/10 
   order by datediff(YYYY, value, getdate())/10 desc
```

this start with 0 then just adds 9
you need to be consistent as 0 - 10 is a range of 11
if you need to start on 1 then I think you need also change the group by